# Given number N eliminate K digits to get maximum possible number

Tags: c++, algorithm

As the title says, the task is:

Given number `N` eliminate `K` digits to get maximum possible number. The digits must remain at their positions.

Example: `n = 12345`, `k = 3`, `max = 45` (first three digits eliminated and digits mustn't be moved to another position).

Any idea how to solve this?
(It's not homework, I am preparing for an algorithm contest and solve problems on online judges.)

`1 <= N <= 2^60`, `1 <= K <= 20`.

Edit: Here is my solution. It's working :)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <queue>
#include <vector>
#include <iomanip>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;


int main()
{
    string n;
    int k;

    cin >> n >> k;

    int b = n.size() - k - 1;
    int c = n.size() - b;
    int ind = 0;
    vector<char> res;
    char max = n.at(0);

    for (int i=0; i<n.size() && res.size() < n.size()-k; i++) {
        max = n.at(i);
        ind = i;
        for (int j=i; j<i+c; j++) {
            if (n.at(j) > max) {
                max = n.at(j);
                ind = j;
            }
        }

        b--;
        c = n.size() - 1 - ind - b;
        res.push_back(max);
        i = ind;
    }

for (int i=0; i<res.size(); i++)
    cout << res.at(i);

cout << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: As posted, this is not a good fit for the site. The goal of SO is to help with solving concrete issues, not to come up with ideas. Show us what you've tried and where you're stuck, then we can help.

Comment: First you need to figure out how to solve it logically. What process do you need to use. Then try to implement that process. Then, if you get stuck, ask us for help on a specific issue.

Comment: "It's not homework, I am preparing for an algorithm contest and solve problems on online judges" -- You are *preparing* by not even trying to solve it?

Comment: I haven't tried anything because I don't have any idea how to solve the problem. That's what i need. An idea, some guidance. Thanks.

Comment: @J.M, It's impossible you don't have *any* idea at all. The brute-forcing version of this algorithm is pretty trivial both logically and syntactically.

Comment: Just think which digits you would want eliminate to get the maximum possible number.

Comment: Think how you got that 45 in your example, what criteria did u used there.

Comment: I think this is best suited for the math, or algorithms, etc... versions of Stack!

Comment: @trumpetlicks I doubt *any* Stack Exchange site will accept a question which shows no research effort *at all.*

Comment: @Angew - good point, some effort should be put forth :-)

Comment: Idea: Find `(n-k)` greatest digits and then find `max` of those `digit + (n-k) digits` after.

Comment: @trumpetlicks ... and [so] would certainly be appropriate if the question did indeed show sufficient research effort (definitely more so than the Mathematics site, and probably slightly, although not excessively, more appropriate than the CS site (there's no "algorithms" site)).

Comment: @noMAD:Failed, try with `n = 2153410`, `k = 3`, `max = 5410`.

Comment: +1, didn't see that coming xD

Comment: Let's make something clear. I have written two solutions about this and neither is correct and i didn't want to post the code here because I wanted to hear some different ideas. I can post the code but that doesn't change anything because the idea it is based upon is incorrect. Thanks

Comment: @J.M But if nothing else, it will show you actually tried something. Even if you don't post the code, at least outline the ideas and why they're flawed (i.e. provide the counter-examples you've found).

Comment: I'll edit my question and I'll post my code. I don't see the point of showing I tried something but ok, It's not a problem. I just wanted to say that i have no `correct` idea to start implementing something.

Comment: @J.M There are so many questions which basically go "gimme teh codez" that showing some effort is pretty much required for a question not to be vanquished.

Comment: Not enough faster to answer :/ I tried that which seems working : https://ideone.com/YqBdNC

Comment: http://tny.cz/bc267c5c here is the code. I don't have it in my editor so i copied from the site i submitted it. The formatting is very bad, i couldn't change it.

Comment: @Jefffrey Could you explain the brute force solution, please?

Comment: calculate all permutations that fit your criteria one at a time and keep track of the highest for brute force method.

Comment: @J.M: My solution (https://ideone.com/YqBdNC) removes digit if the next one is bigger.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Brute force should be fast enough for your restrictions: `n` will have max `19` digits. Generate all positive integers with `numDigits(n)` bits. If `k` bits are set, then remove the digits at positions corresponding to the set bits. Compare the result with the global optimum and update if needed.

Complexity: `O(2^log n * log n)`. While this may seem like a lot and the same thing as `O(n)` asymptotically, it's going to be much faster in practice, because the logarithm in `O(2^log n * log n)` is a base 10 logarithm, which will give a much smaller value (1 + `log base 10` of `n` gives you the number of digits of `n`).

You can avoid the `log n` factor by generating combinations of `n` taken `n - k` at a time and building the number made up of the chosen `n - k` positions as you generate each combination (pass it as a parameter). This basically means you solve the similar problem: `given n, pick n - k digits in order such that the resulting number is maximum`).

**Note:** there is a method to solve this that does not involve brute force, but I wanted to show the OP this solution as well, since he asked how it could be brute forced in the comments. For the optimal method, investigate what would happen if we built our number digit by digit from left to right, and, for each digit `d`, we would remove all currently selected digits that are smaller than it. When can we remove them and when can't we?

Comment: with the first paragraph you mean to use a bitmask?

Answer (score 3):

In the leftmost k+1 digits, find the largest one (let us say it is located at ith location. In case there are multiple occurrences choose the leftmost one). Keep it. Repeat the algorithm for k_new = k-i+1, newNumber = i+1 to n digits of the original number.

```
Eg. k=5 and number = 7454982641
First k+1 digits: 745498
Best number is 9 and it is located at location i=5. 

new_k=1, new number = 82641
First k+1 digits: 82
Best number is 8 and it is located at i=1.

new_k=1, new number = 2641
First k+1 digits: 26
Best number is 6 and it is located at i=2

new_k=0, new number = 41
Answer: 98641
```

Complexity is O(n) where n is the size of the input number.

Edit: As iVlad mentioned, in the worst case complexity can be quadratic. You can avoid that by maintaining a heap of size at most k+1 which will increase complexity to O(nlogk).

Comment: It's correct, but the complexity is `O(n^2)` if you do it like that, for inputs sorted descendingly. You can get `O(n)`.

Comment: Maintaining a heap will still add a `log k` factor. You need to use a stack to get `O(n)`.

Comment: I think you want to say: find the FIRST occurrence of the largest one (since it may repeat).

Answer (score 1):

Following may help:

```
void removeNumb(std::vector<int>& v, int k)
{
    if (k == 0) { return; }
    if (k >= v.size()) {
        v.clear();
        return;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i != v.size() - 1; )
    {
        if (v[i] < v[i + 1]) {
            v.erase(v.begin() + i);
            if (--k == 0) { return; }
            i = std::max(i - 1, 0);
        } else {
            ++i;
        }
    }
    v.resize(v.size() - k);
}
```